# How to use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials to prompt for password only

Tags: c, winapi

I am successfully using `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` to prompt for username and password. I now have a need to prompt the user for password only (i.e. no username field).

This used to be possible with the now deprecated `CredUIPromptForCredentials` using the `CREDUI_FLAGS_PASSWORD_ONLY_OK` flag. However it is not obvious to me how to achieve the same result using `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`.

Comment: You can use CREDUIWIN_IN_CRED_ONLY and provide a caption like "Please enter password:" for the user name and user has to enter password only.